# Possible to make a View not touchable just like a Window in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

A window can be set to not touchable, which means that you can click anything behind that activity just by setting the whole window to not touchable with the following code:

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Now my question is: Is it possible to make only the RelativeLayout NOT TOUCHABLE, I mean the user is able to touch anything behind that RelativeLayout, but he will not be able to touch anything behind the Button in that RelativeLayout.

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    style="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I need the relativelayout to be NOT TOUCHABLE, the user can touch anything behind it.
I only need the button in the relativelayout to be touchable

Hence, Button touchable, RelativeLayout Not Touchable.
I can touch the button, but I can't touch the RelativeLayout I only touch things behind it.

When using
`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);`
The whole window is being set to not touchable with the Button as well, which is not what I want.

I hope my question is understandable.

EDIT:

All i'm trying to do is Displaying a single button on another application (Skype, for example)
I only want that button to be clickable with Skype app together.

Comment: this is exactly same what i'm looking for :) did you get any solution, if yes please post it

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to your `RelativeLayout` this will propagate the events down the view tree.

If that does not work, try overriding this method.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Answer (score 1):

> In your java code write like this

```
ArrayList<View> touchables;
RelativeLayout RelativeLayout_ = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id. rl);
touchables = RelativeLayout_.getTouchables();
for (View touchable : touchables) 
    {
        if (!(touchable.getId()==R.id.button1))
        {
            touchable.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

> Hope it will work

Comment: this didn't work as well. I'm not able to pass touch events through the rl view

Comment: I didn't get you !! Did u use this relative layout only or use some other layout in that xml